# Searching deleted posts in the Android app

Tags: support, android-app, search, deleted-posts

I would like to know how users with 1k reputation can search deleted posts. I don't think they will be searchable through the regular search icon at the top of the Android app, but I don't know.

Comment: TL;DR: they can't. You need 10k (or 2k on beta sites) to search your own deleted posts (that works with `deleted:1`, just like on the website).

Comment: @Glorfindel well the android app (mentioned in the question) doesn't have even that.

Comment: Ah, the iOS app doesn't have it either, since the SE API doesn't return deleted posts.